# Is it possible to order by a non-selected column in Sequel?

Tags: ruby, sequel

Given a table `t` with columns `c1`, `c2` and `cx`, I have a failing [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/index.html) (version 3.27.0) query of the form:

```
DB[:t].order(:cx).select{[:c1, :c2]}
```

I don't need the values from `cx` in my output, I just want them to be used for ordering.

The equivalent SQL would be:

```
SELECT c1, c2 FROM t ORDER BY cx;
```

My current workaround is to just ask for `cx` too, even though I don't need it:

```
DB[:t].order(:cx).select{[:c1, :c2, :cx]}
```

Can anyone confirm that this is a known behavior/bug in Sequel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL produced by Sequel for that code is: `SELECT c1, c2 FROM t ORDER BY cx`.  If it's failing, it's most likely a problem with your database (you'd need to post the backtrace you are getting if you want to debug that).

FWIW, I'd use the following Sequel code: `DB[:t].order(:cx).select(:c1, :c2)`.  There's no reason to use a virtual row block if you aren't using the features it provides.